Is It Possible to Add a Genesis Configuration to a Third-Party Pallet in Substrate?
I am working on a Substrate-based blockchain and need to add a genesis configuration for a pallet that I do not own and cannot modify. My goal is to extend the pallet_identity and add registrars during the genesis for my test chain to avoid adding registrars each time I purge the chain.
Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "T: frame_system::Config")]
pub struct MyPalletGenesisConfig<T: frame_system::Config> {
    pub registrars: Vec<T::AccountId>,
}

impl<T: pallet_identity::Config> BuildGenesisConfig for MyPalletGenesisConfig<T> {
    fn build(&self) {
        for registrar in &self.registrars {
            pallet_identity::Pallet::<T>::add_registrar(frame_system::RawOrigin::Root.into(), registrar_lookup)
                .expect("Failed to add registrar");
        }
    }
}

This code does not work currently. But before I continue to spend time on it I wanted to ask the more experienced ones if its even possible. Maybe there are restrictions that I will face now or later.

Correct me if I am wrong but from my understanding, it is not possible to call a dispatchable function inside the BuildGenesisConfig::build() because the genesis configuration is applied to the runtime before the build process. Hence, the runtime is not fully initialized and it has no context over the dispatchable functions and origins. Hence, we can only call methods that interact with the sp_io::storage directly like put() or set() of the declared storage value.
I took a look at the pallet::identity and seems like all the storage fields are set as pub(super) which you can't access from your custom pallet.

My recommended approach is to fork the pallet-identity to your local Substrate runtime and customize the pallet to have its own BuildGenesisConfig, right now it does not have any. Or you can update the storage field Registrars::set(...).


There is another way to do this. I'd like to avoiding fork and maintain the deps myself as much as possible.
If you fork one, you need to change every other components' source in the Cargo.toml. Especially, when you have frontier, moonbeam deps. There will be so many deps that you need to maintain yourself.
I simply use the pallet_identity::* with frame_support::migration::put_storage_value.
Check our production code, which works well for over a year.

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/2dadcd456ab2d5b0f87af634d8bac979484300d7/pallet/account-migration/src/lib.rs#L438-L465

But I've to say, this way is a little bit hack.
